# .replace() only working once for multiple instances of text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a JQuery UI dialog that presents changes that were made to inputs on a form submit. I'm wanting the word 'New' to be a different color, but it only changes the first occurrence.

Why does the replace() function work for my line breaks, but not for the css change?

[image]

```
 var i;
        for(i = 0; i < changed_arr.length; i++) {

            var oldValue = changed_arr[i].oldValue;
            var newValue = changed_arr[i].newValue;
            str += changed_arr[i].key + ":  Old - " + oldValue + ", New - " + newValue + "\n";
        }
        error_text = $('#dialog_confirm p').text("Please confirm your update\nbefore proceeding.\n\nChanges for <?= $edit_domain;?>: \n\n" + str);
        //The new line works multiple times, but not the css change
        error_text.html(error_text.html().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>').replace('New', '<span style="color:yellow;">New</span>'));

        $('#dialog_confirm').dialog('open');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `g` (global) and possibly the `m` (multi-line) modifier(s) for "New":

```
replace(/New/gm, '<span style="color:yellow;">New</span>')
```

It should replace all occurrences similarly to your line break.

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/Gsv6hc/1

Comment: Removed the quotes around 'New/gm' and it worked. I didn't know how to use replace in the first place, so the line break replacement was the result of a google search, which then resulted in me not learning anything and just pasting syntax. Thank you for explaining the global modifier. Works perfectly.

Comment: For some reason I missed that question when SO showed me similar questions based on my title. My bad. Didn't mean to post a duplicate question. Thanks for pointing that out.